# How to make ybar chart where the final bar start at the end of the other one?

Tags: pgfplots

I want to make a ybar chart like this picture here (sorry for my bad painting skills ;)  )
[image]

So that the bars switch from minus to plus or the other way round and the bar lenght should be noted as a cord in the center of each bar, so its like to sum up vectors. I tried it with 
a waterfall chart but its not the same like in the picture here. Maybe somebody can help me?

here a short example of a code: a bar chart with minus and plus numbers and with a 2 axis environment: Something like that but if one bar goes into minus the bar should start from the end of the last bar and going down to minus

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  symbolic x coords={test1,test2},
  xtick=data,
  x tick label style={rotate=-45,anchor=west},
  xticklabel shift={.5cm},
  ybar stacked,
  bar width=6mm,
  ymin=-50,
  ymax=120,
  legend style={
  at={(1,0.5)},
  anchor=north west,draw=none },
  restrict y to domain*=:0, % negative values
  y=1pt,  % important workaround!
   axis x line*=middle,
   axis y line=left,
    axis on top=false,
    enlarge x limits=0.2,
    nodes near coords,     
    ybar legend,
  ]
  \addplot coordinates {(test1,-11)}; 
  \addplot coordinates {(test1,80)};       
 \legend{blue, red}
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
  symbolic x coords={test1,test2},
  xtick=data,
  x tick label style={rotate=-45,anchor=west},
  xticklabel shift={.5cm},
  ybar stacked,
  bar width=6mm,
  ymin=-50,
  ymax=120,
  legend style={
  at={(1,0.5)},anchor=north west,draw=none },
  restrict y to domain*=0:, % positive values
  y=1pt,  % important workaround!
   axis x line*=middle,
   axis y line=left,
   axis on top=false,
    enlarge x limits=0.2,
    nodes near coords,        
    ybar legend,
  ]
  \addplot coordinates {(test1,-11)}; 
  \addplot coordinates {(test1,80)};   
  \legend{blue, red}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You could have a look in the [manual](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots) for many examples: search for `ybar stacked`.

Comment: HI tanks for your apply!

Comment: no i dont hava an example, i already made a lot of ybar stacked charts but just need a mini example for that kind of problem to work with it.

Comment: something like this here...

Comment: sorry:                                               http://www.techques.com/question/31-53840/ybar-stacked-plot-with-negative-coordinates

Comment: A simple search gives [some results](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpgfplots%5D+waterfall). Is there anything you need? If not, describe your requirement and also update what you get so far.